# Adding handlers to (button) widget in R using addHandlerXXX

Tags: r, handler, gwidgets

I am currently building a GUI based on the R package 'gWidgets2RGtk2'. I want create a button that reacts with a right mouseclick event. Unfortunately, the code below produces a button, but the gmessage is not shown, when right click on the button is performed. Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong?

```
library("gWidgets2")
library("RGtk2")
library("gWidgets2RGtk2")
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")
#
w <- gwindow("main_window_header")
B <- gbutton("?", container = w)
addHandlerRightclick(B, handler = function(h, ...){gmessage("It worked!")})
```

Using the line

```
addHandlerDoubleclick(B, handler = function(h, ...){gmessage("It worked!")})
```

instead of

```
addHandlerRightclick(B, handler = function(h, ...){gmessage("It worked!")})
```

is not showing the gmessage when double-clicking the button. However,

```
addHandler(B, signal = "clicked", handler = function(h, ...){gmessage("It worked!")})
```

is working perfectly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Apparently package "gWidgets" is needed for the right mouseclick handler. Adding

```
library("gWidgets")
```

to the header makes the example work for addHandlerRightclick.